# Perl Mojolicious static files in public not found

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am new to Mojolicious and I have a problem with my .css and .js files placed in public directory. 
My test app was generated by mojo, in template I added

```
<link href="/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Created file test.css i put into public directory, but in log I see

```
[Wed Apr  6 14:27:39 2016] [debug] GET "/test.css"
...
[Wed Apr  6 14:27:39 2016] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.039291s, 25.451/s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What URL are you retrieving? This works fairly well, but you do usually need to check you're getting the right relative paths to URLs based on your routes.

Comment: I didn't change anything in generated new app, so the route is $r->get('/')->to('example#welcome') and in templates/layouts/default.html.ep I just added link to css

Comment: If you created the app with `mojo generate app` and add test.css in the `public` dir you are doing things the right way. Your error is in something you are not telling us.

Comment: Maybe some faulty server configuration. Are you going through a proxy?

Answer (score -2):

Use simply:
`%= stylesheet '/test.css'` in your template.

Comment: Although a nice method i wasn't aware of, this is not an answer that tackles down the op's problem but a workaround.